# Find all the names

Tags: logical-deduction, movies, video-games

> My name is **A** and I am the main character of a video game!
>   Please do not mistake my name for the one of my friend **B** like so many have done before!
>   I saved **B** multiple times but **B** simply won't stop getting in trouble!
>   When it gets dark I sometimes change shape.
>   Do not underestimate me because I sometimes look young for looks can be deceiving and I have many looks I can use to deceive you!
>   As long as I have my sword and my courage, I swear on my name that I shall unify us all!
>   The famous actor **CD** liked my game so much that he used **B**'s name!
>   **CD** once played the character called **FG** in a movie.
>   **FG**, **CE** and me might look very similar, but the 3 of us are not related!

Please find the following names!
-A
-B
-CD
-CE
-FG

Please also explain your reasoning for every clues given.

Comment: Who is Y? Is it meant to be B?

Comment: So sorry, I made an edit mistake. thanks!

Comment: This is just a set of interrelated trivia questions, not a puzzle. The tags "movies" and "video-games" are clues to the trivia involved, but it's trivia nonetheless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My shot:

> A = [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(The_Legend_of_Zelda))
>  B = [Zelda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Zelda)
>  both from the famous "Legend of Zelda"
>  CD = [Robin Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Williams)
>  FG = [Peter Pan](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0417727/?ref_=tt_cl_t2)
>  CE = [Robin Hood](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003908/?ref_=tt_cl_t1)

My name is A and I am the main character of a video game!

> Link is the main character in the video game "Legend of Zelda"

Please do not mistake my name for the one of my friend B like so many have done before!

> [image]

I saved B multiple times but B simply won't stop getting in trouble!

> Self explanatory

When it gets dark I sometimes change shape.
Do not underestimate me because I sometimes look young for looks can be deceiving and I have many looks I can use to deceive you!

> http://zeldawiki.org/Transformation

As long as I have my sword and my courage, I swear on my name that I shall unify us all!

> Link's main weapon is a [sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_of_The_Legend_of_Zelda#Master_Sword) courage is a reference to the [Triforce of Courage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_of_The_Legend_of_Zelda#MTriforce).

The famous actor CD liked my game so much that he used B's name!

> CD = [Robin Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Williams)
>  One of his daughters is named [Zelda Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zelda_Williams)

CD once played the character called FG in a movie.

> Robin Williams played Peter Pan (FG) in the movie [Hook](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102057/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

FG, CE and me might look very similar, but the 3 of us are not related!

> Peter Pan, Robin Hood and Link look similar.  They all have the cute pointy hat and tights :). But there is no relation between the 3 fictional characters.

Comment: the two first lines pointed me into this direction and the rest was just fitting pieces. nicely done tho

Comment: @Marius Well you basically just won the whole thing. Good job. It's the 3rd time today that my puzzle get answered within the first 2-3 views so it's a little vexing though XD. I really tried hard this time, but still too easy I guess. It would really make my day if you could explain the "change shape in the dark", "sometimes look young", "have many looks to deceive you", "courage", "on my name... unify us all" and maybe also explain how you found CE except for the "looking similar part"

Comment: @stackreader. Don't despair. It was a really nice puzzle. I had fun solving it.  What give it away is "Please do not mistake my name for the one of my friend B". I think this is the most seen name confusion in the game history. I cannot really explain all the hints because I didn't play the game (bow head in shame). I can look online for them if you really want. As for "CE". I new what "C" means and just thought about the other famous "C's". The first one that comes to mind is "CE" :)

Comment: Wow, for someone who didn't play the games to know so much is quite impressive! I will give you the "accepted answer" as you obviously deserve and hopefully other people will come and find the details later on.

Comment: I explained 2 more references. I'll see what I can do for the rest.